# Paypal Button JS plugin : Testing in sandbox

Tags: paypal

I have created the shopping cart button using Paypal Button JS plugin (http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/).

The  button code is like this

```
<script 
data-env="sandbox" 
data-callback="http://mysite.com" 
data-tax="10" 
data-shipping="10" 
data-currency="USD" 
data-amount="100" 
data-name="TestProduct" 
data-button="cart" src="paypal-button-minicart.min.js?merchant=test@yahoo.com"
```

>

I downloaded the java script from the link given above. I have created the merchant and buyer account from paypal sandbox site.

But When I trying to test in my local/test environment it is going to live paypal site(do not accepting my sandbox buyer account). Please help me to test in the sand box environment.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your checkout on your site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today and it looks like a bug with the paypal-button-minicart.min.js script. Apparently this was fixed back in April according to GitHub but still seems to be an issue.

I got this working by editing the file and searching for "www.paypal" and replacing the instance with "www.sandbox.paypal"

I also had a problem with my test account email - so I created a second merchant account in the developer tools and put that in the "minicart.min.js?merchant=test@yahoo.com" section and was up and running.

Not a good solution I know, but a solution none the less.

Comment: It worked after updating the paypal.com with sandbox.paypal.com. But I am facing another issue now . ....After checkout the cart is not getting cleared. I see the old items in the cart

Comment: Hrmm.. Yeah! Same problem here. I'm still battling what looks like not getting an IPN postback but have had some other things come up so not focusing on again. If you get a solution to clearing the cart would love to know!

Comment: It looks like they did indeed fix the issues, but they haven't cut a release. If you're downloading the js file, download it from github#master instead of the file they provide. If you're using Bower, make sure it's #master instead of ~0.9.whatever

Answer (score -2):

add this 
data-host="www.sandbox.paypal.com"